# Is there a better way to perform "x = y ? y : x"? Specifically in JS

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

It just seems so redundant and ugly. I've been using that expression quite often lately and there has to be another way.

"Assign y to x if it is valid otherwise leave x unchanged"

```
x = y ? y : x
```

Comment: `if (y) x = y;` is easier to read.

Comment: And in fact saves an operation, whenever y = 0

Comment: `x = y || x;` is quite idiomatic IMHO (like in `opts = opts || {};`)

Comment: The idiomatic Javascript way is `x = y || x`

Comment: Thanks Thilo, that is indeed slightly more pleasant to look at. For the logical 'or' way, see my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this, by using logical `or`

```
x = y || x;
```

If `y` is `truthy`, `x` will be equal to y after assignment.

Else `x` will be the same.

**Here is an explanation**

Look for the **Other types** section: [mdn re-introduction to javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

**UPDATE:** If you plan on using **bitwise operators** to do the trick, please take note that it only works with **32 bits integers** to swap such values as `x` and `y` mentionned above.

Comment: But what happens when they are both valid? I tested it, it seems to pick the first value, I assume it's reliable?

Comment: Thanks. You would think with how common this seems to be there would be a '|=' or something